# React Component Not Re Rendering using Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, state

I've tried other solutions on this site, but I am not sure why this is not working. I have a response I am getting from a server each time a button is pressed. The response comes through fine and I am able to see it each time the button is pressed. I am receiving an array of objects from the server, and I am using the useState hook to set the state of a variable to keep track of the objects in the array. However, the component does not re render. Interestingly, if I add a console.log statement to see the contents of the state variable and then save the page, I can see that the state variable was updated properly. The component still does not re render though. The relevant code is here:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
import tailwind from "tailwind-rn";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import AppText from "../components/AppText";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { getData } from "../hooks/useCache";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import ListScreen from "./ListScreen";

const ProfileScreen = () => {
  const { logout, user } = useAuth();
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState("");
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState("");
  const [responseJson, setResponseJson] = useState(null);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    const likesFunc = async() => {
    setLikes(await getData("likes"));
    setCompleted(await getData("eventsCompleted"));
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "server url here",
        {
          headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + user.idToken },
        }
      );
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      setLikes(responseJson.likes);
      setCompleted(responseJson.eventsCompleted);
    } catch {
      Alert.alert("There has been an error processing your profile");
    }
  }
  likesFunc();
  }, []);

  //get voted events
  //run when questionsLeft is 0 to save num of calls
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventFunction = async() => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "server url here",
            {
              headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + user.idToken },
            }
          )
          const res = await response.json();
          setResponseJson([...res]);
        
        } catch (error) {
          Alert.alert(
            "An error has occurred loading your questions. Close the app and try again."
          );
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
      eventFunction();
  }, [isFocused]);

  return (
    <Screen style={styles.bg}>
      <View
        style={[
          tailwind("w-full flex-row py-4 justify-center items-center top-0"),
          { justifyContent: "space-between" },
        ]}
      >
        <AppText style={{ color: colors.white, fontSize: 30, marginLeft: 5 }}>
          Hello, {user.displayName.split(" ")[0]}
        </AppText>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.logoutButton}
          onPress={() => {
            Alert.alert("Log Out", "Are you sure you want to log out?", [
              {
                text: "Yes",
                style: "destructive",
                onPress: logout,
              },
              {
                text: "Cancel",
                style: "cancel",
              },
            ]);
          }}
        >
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="logout-variant"
            size={25}
            color={colors.primary}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View
        style={tailwind("w-full h-1/5 justify-center items-center")}
      >
        <View
          style={[
            tailwind("w-full flex-row p-10 justify-center"),
            { justifyContent: "space-between" },
          ]}
        >
          <View style={tailwind("justify-center items-center")}>
            <AppText style={{ textDecorationLine: "underline" }}>
              Total Likes
            </AppText>
            <AppText style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>{likes}</AppText>
          </View>

          <View style={tailwind("justify-center items-center")}>
            <AppText style={{ textDecorationLine: "underline" }}>
              Completed
            </AppText>
            <AppText style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>{completed}</AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={tailwind("w-full h-4/5 flex-1 items-center")}
      >
        {responseJson == null ? 
        <AppText style={tailwind("mt-10")}>
          Select events on the "Discover" page!
        </AppText>
        : 
          <ListScreen caller={{"sender": "profile", "json": responseJson}}/>
        }
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
};

export default ProfileScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logoutButton: {
    color: colors.white,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingRight: 10,
  },
  bg: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.black,
  },
});
```

Update: If I set the state twice in a row, it works:

```
setResponseJson(null);
setResponseJson([...res]);
```

However, this is somewhat buggy and not optimal. Leads me to think it still is a reference issue, but I am not sure why the spread operator technique does not fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Three things are wrong/weird in your code. Not sure it will fix your problem but here are they :

1- Do not pass an async function to the `useEffect`. Instead, create an async function inside and call it :

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myFunc = async => {...};
  myFunc();
},[]);
```

2- You are receiving an array of objects from your api call, so why do you want to spread it ? It would lead to multiple objects inside your state, which doesn't seems right. Just pass your `res` in your state as is or format it as you want.

3- You are mixing `async/await` pattern with the `.then`. Either use an async func and await the result :

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  const resPromise = await fetch(...);
  const json = await resPromise.json();
  ...
}
```

or only use the `.then`:

```
  const myFunc = () => {
  fetch(...)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => ...);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I made the async change. My idea with using the spread operator was to create a new array so the state hook knows that the state was updated. I've read that if the reference to the array remains the same, the component will not re render.

Comment: @Roche You are mixing `async/await` pattern with the `.then`. Either use an async func and await the results, or do not use an async func and use the `.then`. If it  doesn't change anything, I don't see what could cause this in your code, give us a repro or more code so we can properly check it.

Comment: yup you are right. I still don't see the component re render though. I really appreciate the help

Comment: @Roche Have you updated your question with your new code ? I updated my answer to give you example on how to use async/await or .then().

Comment: yes I updated it, hopefully you can see the change?

Comment: @Roche Yes thank you. So as expected, I see no problem with your code here. Please share the rest of your code so we can check it.

Comment: Just posted the full code file, minus the server url